# Docker Unable to Expose port on MacOs

Tags: docker

In simple *hello world app* in Node.js the port forwarding seems not to be working. When I am inside container and I run curl, I get correct response. Anyway from the main os I get empty reply from server.

Command `docker container exec -it vigorous_knuth curl 127.0.0.1:80` produces **Hello World**

Command `curl 127.0.0.1:80` produces **curl: (52) Empty reply from server**

OS: MacOs 12.1

Docker: Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /code

COPY . .

ENV PORT 80

EXPOSE $PORT

RUN npm install curl

CMD ["node", "app.js", "&"]
```

App:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 80;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Command:

`docker run -p 80:80  site:0.0.16`

Comment: Try `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` to listen on all interfaces, not just the loopback.

Comment: @frippe Thanks, it solved the issue.